# Silverlight 3 List box

Tags: silverlight

How to set the orientation of the List box in Silverlight i.e how to  display the data horizontally?

Answer (score 4):

Modify the ItemsPanel of the ListBox and set it to a StackPanel that's oriented Horizontally:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: I thought it would be answered before I could hit "post!"

Comment: ok, more elegant solution than mine. But my idea still works. ;-)

Comment: Scott, the answer you provided may look like horizontal listbox, but really that is not. You cant do a DataBinding on the listbox. The default panel associated with a listBox is StackPanel with Vertical orientation so just make that horizontal is the only right answer.

Comment: i noticed that your example wasn't letting the user select those listboxitems separately but i wasn't going to say anything ;)