# display multiple data horizontally

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-2.0

how to display data horizontally in a list box. I had used the properties for reading data from the text box and i have to display these multiple data in to a list box (in one line, horizontally) . my code is shown below..

```
private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        LoadData();



    }

private void LoadData()
    {
        List<ItemList> MyList = new List<ItemList>();
        MyList.Add(new ItemList { Subject = subjectText.Text });
        MyList.Add(new ItemList { Createdtext = CreatedText.Text });
        MyList.Add(new ItemList { Calendartext = CalendarText.Text });
        MyList.Add(new ItemList { TimeText = TimeText.Text });
        MyList.Add(new ItemList { AssignedText = AssignedText.Text });
        MyList.Add(new ItemList { DescriptionText = DescriptText.Text });
        MyList.Add(new ItemList { TargetdateText = TargetDateText.Text });

        MyListBox.ItemsSource = MyList;

    }
```

The property for getting data is:

```
public class ItemList
{
    private string _subject;
    private string _createdtext;
    private string _calendartext;
    private string _timeText;
    private string _assignedText;
    private string _descriptionText;
    private string _targetdateText;


    public string Subject
    {
        get
        {
            return _subject;
        }
        set
        {
            _subject = value;
        }
    }

    public string Createdtext
    {
        get
        {
            return _createdtext;
        }
        set
        {
            _createdtext = value;
        }
    }

    public string Calendartext
    {
        get
        {
            return _calendartext;
        }

        set
        {
            _calendartext = value;
        }
    }

    public string TimeText
    {
        get
        {
            return _timeText;
        }

        set
        {
            _timeText = value;
        }
    }

    public string AssignedText
    {
        get
        {
            return _assignedText;
        }

        set
        {
            _assignedText = value;
        }
    }

    public string DescriptionText
    {
        get
        {
            return _descriptionText;
        }

        set
        {
            _descriptionText = value;
        }
    }

    public string TargetdateText
    {
        get
        {
            return _targetdateText;
        }

        set
        {
            _targetdateText = value;
        }
    }
}
```

My XAML code for List box is shown below

```
<ListBox x:Name="MyListBox" ItemsSource="ItemList" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="8" Width="600" Height="96">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" >
                    <Grid ShowGridLines="True" Width="700">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="25" />

                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Subject}" Grid.Column="0"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Createdtext}"  Grid.Column="1" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Calendartext}" Grid.Column="2" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Timetext}" Grid.Column="3"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding AssignedText}"  Grid.Column="4"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DescriptionText}"  Grid.Column="5" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TargetdateText}"  Grid.Column="6"/>
                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

but i didn't get the output in one line. it displayed in diagonally.. What are the changes required for getting correct output..

Comment: This is a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165236/silverlight-3-list-box

Answer (score 2):

```
<ListBox x:Name="MyListBox" ItemsSource="ItemList" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="8" Width="600" Height="96">
...
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
...
</ListBox>
```

try this

Comment: Is the <VirtualizingStackPanel> tag available on silverlight 2.0??

Comment: No, unfortunately `VirtualizingStackPanel` is not in Silverlight 2.0 or 3.0. Try to use `StackPanel` instead.

Comment: you are right, VirtualizingStackPanel only in WPF use StackPanel instead

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [MSDN page for the `ItemsPanel` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemspanel(VS.95).aspx). It has an example demonstrating how to create a horizontal list box.